# How to get all the LineStrings of a street using PostGIS with OSM

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, query, osm2pgsql, streets

I want to get all parts of a given street.

I use a query like:
    `Select * from  planet_osm_lines where name = 'mystreet'`

As a result I get all the LineStrings that are part of a street with the given name, but somehow I have to group the LineStrings to form the correct MultiLinestrings, because there could be other streets with the name "mystreet".

Does someone know how to get this information?

Comment: You could check iteratively if line segments touch each other by using "ST_StartPoint" and "ST_EndPoint" or "ST_Touches". If so, then merge the lines and you should be able to group them.

Comment: that sounds like a possible way, thank you. But isn't this information maybe stored in any Relationship or something like this?

Comment: Streets ade not modelled as relations in OSM. What C.B. suggests is the best that you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ST_LineMerge http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html

First you need join all your ways into one MultiLineString using ST_DUMP http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html and ST_Multy

Afterwards use ST_LineMerge to get a set of Linestrings of maximum length sewed from segments.